Memory Error when computing ODE solutions
I am modelling a Klein-Gordon equation (similar to a wave equation), by mode decomposition, i.e. I need to solve the eigenvalue problem y_n'' = - omega_n ** 2 * y (This is of course a vast simplification).
This procedure involves many steps, but the main ones are

Calculate the solution for each of the modes (identified with an index n) up to a maximum index max_n. Save it to the nth element of a solution array of the class I am using to do all this (as this is all part of a bigger project).

for n in range(-max_n, max_n+1):
    self.solution_array[n+max_n] = scipy.integrate.solve_bvp(
        Klein_Gordon_differential_equation,
        boundary_conditions,
        ...,
        p=(eigenvalue_guess(n),),
        )

This is suboptimal as I am not doing any parallelization.

When all these modes are calculated, calculate some physical quantity regarding the full family of solutions, which changes the context of the problem.

With this new context, repeat step 1.

If some convergence is achieved, stop.


When trying to solve for the eigenvalue, SciPy raises a MemoryError: Not enough memory to perform factorization.
Is there anyway I change my method so that I do not get a MemoryError? For example, is it possible that since I am not using parallelization, SciPy 'sees' less memory than what it should be seeing? i.e. will parallelization solve something more than just runtime?
Note: Please tell me if I need to add more details. The process in itself its pretty simple, but the calculations I am doing involve a lot of subcalculations that I do not think are relevant for the question.
Edit: The traceback of the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 45, in <module>
    smoothing=smoothing,
  File "/home/sanz/MasterArbeit/computation/calculations/increase_lambda.py", line 84, in main
    plt.show()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 254, in show
    return _show(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 3266, in show
    cls.mainloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 1039, in mainloop
    managers[0].window.mainloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1283, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
KeyboardInterrupt

Edit: Other probably relevant information: The code breaks down due to physical reasons (when the eigenvalue of some mode goes to 0, due to the external electric field being too strong). When that happens, I understand that scipy tries to increase the number of nodes used with each iteration. I guess that is where the memory error is
Edit: This is the smallest working example I could think of. It is very flunky as some variables kind of change contextually, as usually this all is part of a bigger class and I can just call self.thing.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpmath import quad
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

from itertools import cycle

def sign(x):
    # Returns sign of x
    return 2 * (x>0) - 1 

def float_in_array(x, array, tol=1e-3):
    # Checks if x is in given array up to some tolerance
    for element in array:
        if abs(x - element) < tol: 
            return True
    return False


def A0(z):
    # This is horrible I know. Usually all this is done inside a class
    # A0_induced should be a CubicSpline
    return - lambda_value * (z- 1/2) + a * A0_induced(z)

def eigenvalue_guess(n):
    # energy of a massless free particle
    return n * np.pi

def dirichlet_eigenstate(z, omega_n):
    # A first order approximation of a solution guess for the Klein-Gordon equation
    n = sign(omega_n) / np.pi

    if n == 0:
        return 0

    eigenstate = abs(omega_n) ** -(1 / 2) * (
        np.sin(np.pi * n * z)
        + lambda_value
        * omega_n
        / (2 * np.pi * abs(n))
        * ((1 / 2 - z) / np.pi / n * np.sin(np.pi * n * z) - z * (1 - z) * np.cos(np.pi * n * z))
    )

    return eigenstate

def dirichlet_eigenstate_gradient(z, omega_n):
    n = sign(omega_n) / np.pi

    if n == 0:
        return 0

    eigenstate_gradient = abs(omega_n) ** -(1 / 2) * (
        np.cos(np.pi * n * z) * np.pi * n
        + lambda_value
        * omega_n
        * (
            (
                -1 / np.pi / n * np.sin(np.pi * n * z)
                + (1 / 2 - z) * np.cos(np.pi * n * z)  # Deriv of first term
                - (1 - z) * np.cos(np.pi * n * z)
                + z * np.cos(np.pi * n * z)
            )
            + np.pi * n * z * (1 - z) * np.sin(np.pi * n * z)
        )
        / (2 * np.pi * abs(n))
    )

    return eigenstate_gradient

def Klein_Gordon_equation(
    z_array,
    f,
    p,
    ):
    # The differential equation
    omega_n = p[0] # Eigenvalue of the nth mode

    background_field = A0(z_array)

    klein_gordon = np.array(
        (f[1], -((omega_n - background_field) ** 2) * f[0])
    )

    return klein_gordon

def Dirichlet_bcs(ya, yb, p):
    # Since we are finding the eigenvalue,
    # need an additional BC to solve the equation.
    # y'(1) = 1 is arbitrary but preserves generality
    # as long as the solution to the ODE is later normalized
    bcs = np.array((ya[0], yb[0], yb[1] - 1))
    return bcs

def calculate_eigenstates(max_N):

    eigenvalues = []
    eigenstates = []
    eigenstate_gradients = []

    for n in range(-max_N, max_N+1):
        if n == 0:
            continue # Non physical case

        omega_n = eigenvalue_guess(n) # the eigenvalue guess

        # The guess for the solution, and its derivative, as
        # its solving a 2nd order differential eq
        y = (
                dirichlet_eigenstate(z, omega_n),
                dirichlet_eigenstate_gradient(z, omega_n),
                )
        eigenstate = solve_bvp(
                Klein_Gordon_equation,
                Dirichlet_bcs,
                z, # The x-axis,
                y,
                p=(omega_n,),
                max_nodes=9e19,
                )
        omega_n = eigenstate.p[0]

        if not eigenstate.success:
            # Sometimes the ODE doesnt converge
            raise Exception(f"Solution associated with omega_n={omega_n} did not converge")

        if float_in_array(omega_n, eigenvalues):
            # Sometimes an eigenvalue converges to another possible solution
            raise Exception(f"Found repeated eigenvalue {omega_n}")

        eigenvalues.append(omega_n)
        eigenstates.append(eigenstate.sol(z)[0])
        eigenstate_gradients.append(eigenstate.sol(z)[1])

    return {
            "eigenvalues": eigenvalues,
            "eigenstates": eigenstates,
            "eigenstate_gradients": eigenstate_gradients,
            }

def normalize_eigenstate_family(solution_family:dict):
    # Due to the boundary conditions, the solutions are not normalized
    # This assumes that the A0 is somewhere defined.

    # Had to initiate the dict again, I am not sure why
    # If I don't do it, it doesn't really update.
    eigenvalues = solution_family["eigenvalues"]
    eigenstates = []
    eigenstate_gradients = []
    # Warning, math
    for n, (eigenvalue, eigenstate, eigenstate_gradient) in enumerate(
            zip(
            solution_family["eigenvalues"],
            solution_family["eigenstates"],
            solution_family["eigenstate_gradients"],
            )
            ):

        eigenstate = CubicSpline(z, eigenstate)

        def rho_n_without_normalizing(z):
            # Normalizing wrt the symplectic norm
            # the solutions need not be real.
            return (eigenvalue - A0(z)) * abs(eigenstate(z))**2

        # Calculate the norm
        norm_squared = abs(float(quad(rho_n_without_normalizing, [0, 1])))

        norm = np.sqrt(norm_squared)

        eigenstates.append(eigenstate(z)/norm)
        eigenstate_gradients.append(eigenstate_gradient/norm)

    return {
            "eigenvalues":eigenvalues,
            "eigenstates":eigenstates,
            "eigenstate_gradients":eigenstate_gradients,
            }

def calculate_rho(solution_family:dict):
    # If the solutions are not normalized this does not work
    # Again, this assumes that A0 is defined somewhere before this function is called
    eigenvalues = solution_family["eigenvalues"]
    eigenstates = solution_family["eigenstates"]

    # The total charge density. 
    # Initiate as np.array to add them
    rho = np.zeros_like(z) 

    for n, (eigenvalue, eigenstate) in enumerate(
            zip(
                eigenvalues,
                eigenstates,
                )
            ):
        # The charge density associated to the nth mode
        # eigenstate is np array. A0 is a callable. 
        # A0(z) is of the same shape as eigenstate
        rho_n = (eigenvalue - A0(z)) * abs(eigenstate) ** 2
        rho += rho_n

    return rho


def filter_rho(rho):
    """
    Parameters:
        rho: a noisy signal (with a very particular kind of noise)
    Returns:
        rho_filtered: the filtered signal.
    """
    # This exploits the fact that we know exactly what the 
    # noise looks like. It can be convoluted away with
    # a very specific function. Not particularly
    # relevant.

    # As long as n_points is exactly 8 * (max_N + 1),
    # the filtering should work fine
    # As with A0, n_points, max_N are necessarily
    # defined somewhere before the function is called.
    delta_N = n_points // ( max_N + 1) + 1
    convoluting_array = [0] * delta_N

    # Some fine tuned parameters
    surround_peaks = 0.00
    peaks = 0.4
    middle = 6
    edges = 3

    # On the borders
    convoluting_array[0] = edges
    convoluting_array[-1] = edges

    # Peak of the sine
    convoluting_array[delta_N // 4 + 1] = surround_peaks
    convoluting_array[delta_N // 4 - 1] = surround_peaks

    # Trough of the sine
    convoluting_array[3 * (delta_N // 4) + 1] = surround_peaks
    convoluting_array[3 * (delta_N // 4) - 1] = surround_peaks

    convoluting_array[delta_N // 4] = peaks
    convoluting_array[3 * (delta_N // 4)] = peaks

    # In the middle of the curve
    convoluting_array[delta_N // 2] = middle

    # Normalizing it so that we don't get extra factors
    convoluting_array = np.array(convoluting_array) / sum(convoluting_array)

    rho_filtered = np.convolve(rho, convoluting_array, mode="same")
 
    return rho_filtered # This will stield yield some noise as 
                      # this is not the full smoothing algorithm.

def calculate_A0_induced(rho):
    rho_interpolated = CubicSpline(z, rho)
    # Math: 
    # Since gauge freedom, I can choose the offset of the induced field.
    # Due to the antisymmetry of the induced rho, I can choose this
    # offset so that the A0 field is antisymmetric with respect to
    # the midpoint z=1/2
    A0_induced_shifted = rho_interpolated.antiderivative(2)
    offset = A0_induced_shifted(1/2)
    # This forces A0_induced(1/2) = 0
    # The minus sign is because physics.
    A0_induced = lambda z: -(A0_induced_shifted(z) - offset)

    return A0_induced

def plot_rho_A0_induced(
        rho, 
        A0_induced,
        fmt,
        color,
        alpha,
        ):
    ax_rho.plot(z, rho, fmt, color=color, alpha=alpha)
    ax_A0_induced.plot(z, A0_induced, fmt, color=color, alpha=alpha)


def calculate_A0_total(A0_induced):
    # A0_induced is a function
    return lambda z: -lambda_value * (z - 1/2) + a*A0_induced(z)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    plot = True
    if plot:
        fig, (ax_rho, ax_A0_induced, ax_eigenvalues) = plt.subplots(3)
        eigenvalues_array = []
        lambda_array = []

    # Number of modes
    n_points = 200
    # x-axis
    z = np.linspace(0, 1, n_points)

    a = 1
    max_N = 1 #24 # Cutoff for the mode solutions
               # Note that there will be 2 * max_N - 1 solutions
    lambda_min = 7 # Strength of the external electric field
    lambda_max = 18 # Strength of the external electric field
    lambda_step= 0.25

    n_iterations = 15 # Number of iterations for each value of lambda

    # Need to initialize the A0_induced
    A0_induced = CubicSpline(z, np.zeros_like(z))
    color_cycle = cycle(["#FE5F55","#3423A6","#710627","#7180B9","#163B20"])

    for i, lambda_value in enumerate(np.arange(lambda_min, lambda_max, lambda_step)):
        print('λ =', lambda_value)
        color = next(color_cycle) # To distinguish between different lambda values
        if lambda_value == 17.0:
            print('We got here, increasing n_iterations')
            n_iterations *= 2
        try:
            for n in range(n_iterations):
                solution_family = calculate_eigenstates(max_N)

                normalized_solution_family = normalize_eigenstate_family(solution_family)

                rho = calculate_rho(normalized_solution_family)
                # rho = filter_rho(rho)
                A0_induced = calculate_A0_induced(rho)

                A0 = calculate_A0_total(A0_induced)
                if plot and not i%3:
                    plot_rho_A0_induced(rho, A0_induced(z), '--', color=color, alpha=0.5)
                if not n: # For the first iteration
                    print('n=0, max(A0_induced) =', max(A0_induced(z)))
                
            if plot:
                eigenvalues_array.append(solution_family["eigenvalues"])
                lambda_array.append(lambda_value)
                plot_rho_A0_induced(rho, A0_induced(z), '', color=color, alpha=1)
            # print(f'n={n_iterations}, max(A0_induced) =', max(A0_induced(z)))
            A0 = calculate_A0_total(lambda z: (lambda_value + lambda_step)/lambda_value * A0_induced(z))
        # In case of exception, plot whatever was calculated
        except Exception as exception:
            e = exception
            break
        except KeyboardInterrupt as exception:
            e = exception
            break

    if plot:
        ax_eigenvalues.plot(lambda_array, eigenvalues_array, 'b')
        plt.show()
    
    raise e



Have you tried modules like https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html ? there are means to share memory between subprocessing "workers", but I can't tell if it'll fit your need. My first shot would be to encapsulate the loop call into a callable class, then use multiprocessing pool .map : it'll will "parallelize", and then return a list of whatever the callable outputs.

The question is : what is the root cause of memory error ? I guess it's the array storing too many big elements ? or is it solve_bvp that uses lots of memory by itself ? can you produce a MCVE of this loop (mainly, relevant input data, actual value of max_n and what does eigenvalue_guess()?

Which step do you compute the eigenvalues? What is the shape of the matrix? What is the data type of the matrix?

"For example, is it possible that since I am not using parallelization, SciPy 'sees' less memory than what it should be seeing? i.e. will parallelization solve something more than just runtime?" No. In fact, parallelization will increase memory usage, not decrease it. It won't solve a MemoryError.

There's not enough information to determine why this is running out of memory. This question needs a minimal, reproducble example. It would also be useful if you posted a traceback, to determine what part of SciPy triggers the MemoryError.

I am right now writing the MWE, but since it is a multi step process, it will be many lines long. something that might be relevant is: The code breaks down due to physical reasons (when the eigenvalue of some mode goes to 0, due to the external electric field being too strong). When that happens, I understand that scipy tries to increase the number of nodes used with each iteration. I guess that is where the memory error is.
